# C++ Function or not a Function Pointer Compiling Error

Tags: c++

I just created a second account for some questioning in regards to C++. I am a beginner in this language, but I understand almost all of it since I have prior knowledge of Java and Python. The code welcomes the user and then asks for a ticket, historical P/E, book value, and earnings per share. The piece of code that is giving the error includes a specific wording of the type of primitive data type not being able to compute since it is or isn't a function pointer. I have right here the question about an error I am receiving by trying to build a Benjamin Graham stock predictor in C++:

**Piece of code that has an error:**

`intrinsicValue = sqrt (15 * 1.5(earningsPerShare)(bookValuePerShare));`

**Actual error inside compiler:**

```
main.cpp:33:36: error: called object type 'double' is not a function or function
      pointer
    intrinsicValue = sqrt (15 * 1.5(earningsPerShare)(bookValuePerShare));
                                ~~~^
1 error generated.
```

Thank you in advance for your help, any solutions or alternatives would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: C++ doesn't assume multiplication when operator is missing. You need `*` between all the values - `15 * 1.5 * earningsPerShare * bookValuePerShare`

Comment: If you are talking about Stack Overflow accounts, *I just created a second account for some questioning in regards to C++.* isn't a good thing to mention in the Stack Overflow question. It makes you look like you're trying to make dodgy end run around a posting restriction.

Comment: Ah sorry for saying that then, I couldn't find the password to my first account. Thanks for the answer @Yksisarvinen!